# Уравнивание пользователей в одном датасете по значениям из другого Python (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

У меня есть 2 датасета (для примера взял минимальный набор):

```
dict1 = [{'user_id': 100, 'bonus': 1},{'user_id': 101, 'bonus': 3}, {'user_id': 102, 'bonus': 1}]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
df1.head()
    user_id bonus
0   100     1
1   101     3
2   102     1

dict2 = query1 = [{'LVL': 'LVL1', 'user_id': 100},{'LVL': 'LVL2', 'user_id': 101}, {'LVL': 'LVL3', 'user_id': 101}, {'LVL': 'LVL4', 'user_id': 101},{'LVL': 'LVL5', 'user_id': 102}]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict2)
df2.head()

    LVL     user_id
0   LVL1    100
1   LVL2    101
2   LVL3    101
3   LVL4    101
4   LVL5    102
```

df1 - уникальные пользователи и количество бонусов у них

df2 - уровни для пользователей (уникальные) и пользователи на них.

Мне необходимо написать функцию или просто обработку, которая перераспределяла бы количество bonus из df1 равномерно между user_id в таблицу df2, т.е. если у одного user_id количество bonus в df1 составляет 3 (как у user_id = 101) то для ближайшего LVL (с этим user_id) в датасете df2 должен присвоиться user_id с наименьшим количеством бонусов.
То есть на выходе я должен получить:

```
    LVL     user_id
0   LVL1    100
1   LVL2    100
2   LVL3    101
3   LVL4    101
4   LVL5    102
```

Т.е. я уравниваю количество LVL на одного уникального user_id в датасете df2 в зависимости от количество bonus у user_id из датасета df1. И делаю я это до тех пор, пока разница между максимальным значением bonus и минимальным не будет равна 1

Я начал делать следующее:
ищу в первом датасете user_id с максимальным количеством бонусов:

```
max_bonus_user = df1.iloc[[df1['user_id'].idxmax()]]['user_id']
max_bonus_user
102

max_bonus = df1.iloc[[df1['bonus'].idxmax()]]['bonus']
max_bonus
3
```

и с минимальным:

```
min_bonus_user = df1.iloc[[df1['user_id'].idxmin()]]['user_id']
min_bonus_user
100

min_bonus = df1.iloc[[df1['bonus'].idxmin()]]['bonus']
min_bonus
1
```

сравниваю max_bonus с min_bonus. Если (max_bonus - min_bonus > 1) то мне нужно в df2 для ближайшего LVL с user_id с максимальным max_bonus заменить user_id на user_id с минимальным min_bonus.
Помогите придумать алгоритм для такой обработки в цикле, всю голову себе сломал.

Comment: Если честно, очень мудрёно описана задача. Можно как-то попроще с конкретным примером?

Comment: Попробую привести другой пример:
Есть список студентов (df1) и на каждого назначено какое-то кол-во задач (например, Иван - 1 задача, Петя - 3 задачи, Федя - 1 задача).
Есть список уникальных задач (df2) и за каждой закреплен студент (задача 1 - Иван, задача 2 - Петя, задача 3- Петя, задача 4 - Петя, задача 5- Федя).
Необходимо в зависимости от кол-ва задач на студенте распределить их так, чтобы разница в кол-ве у каждого была не более 1 задачи (т.е. уравнять нагрузку).
Получить в итоге на данном примере (задача 1 - Иван, задача 2 - Иван, задача 3- Петя, задача 4 - Петя, задача 5- Федя)

Comment: Ещё сложность заключается в том, что в df1 могут быть студенты, с количеством задач 0, т.е. их нет в df2, и на таких в первую очередь необходимо распределять задачи.